# How to generate table of contents with prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation, prawn

Is there an easy way to generate table of contents with links to corresponding pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prawn: Table of content with page numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911663/prawn-table-of-content-with-page-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent-ish versions of prawn, yes. Check out the examples/general/outlines.rb example for API samples.

See http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf p. 96

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911663/prawn-table-of-content-with-page-numbers